# HTML Tags in PHP Create Image

Tags: php, html, image, gd

I'm trying to create an image in PHP, while also giving the image a title and meta tags. I'm using the code below but the HTML does nothing. I do see the image though.

```
<?php
    $IMGID = $_GET['id'];
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($IMGID . ".png");
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: An `image/png` isn't HTML. Take a look at http://www.phpforkids.com/php/php-gd-library-adding-text-writing.php.

Comment: I know it isn't, but I would like to be able to have HTML header tags somehow as well.

Comment: Maybe generate it as a base64 image and put it in an `img` tag.

Comment: "I know it isn't, but I would like to be able to have HTML header tags somehow as well." - Two entirely separate requests / responses - one is an HTML document, one is an image that is linked to from that HTML document. Just as you would if you created an HTML page linking to a static image. The "static image" is instead your PHP script.